# ITunesConnect rejecting build even though I'm on normal Xcode version

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting the following error and don't understand why I am getting it. I'm running Xcode 7.2.1 which is the normal released version and was able to upload builds earlier this week with this same Xcode version so this error makes no sense. Has anyone else encountered it or figured a way to get rid of it? I've tried the following:

1. Restarted Xcode
2. Deleted Derived Data
3. Restarted Computer
4. Ran Build Clean
5. Ran Build Folder Clean
6. Incremented versions on the build.

Any other ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I think, the best possible option is contact Apple support regarding this issue.

Comment: Apple has clearly been doing some house-cleaning. A lot of Apple IDs suddenly went bad yesterday and today (their email addresses needed new verification). You might try getting on to the Member Center or http://appleid.apple.com and see whether that helps.

Comment: I filed a bug with Apple, and went to member center and re-downloaded my dev provisioning profile, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: @matt What do you mean by verify your apple id? I went to member center and poked around and nothing seemed out of the normal.

Comment: I don't know if the apple id problems are related to what you're experiencing, but something has been going on today and yesterday.

Comment: @matt, I filed a bug report, but do you suggest contacting support some other way? I haven't had much contact with Apple Support in the past so am not quite sure whats the typical process when you get something quirky like this (other than sit and wait for it to magically fix itself)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/contact/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out what was wrong with it, and it is definitely my fault. As stated in the error message:

> Don't submit apps with Beta software including OS X builds

Xcode was on the correct version but my OSX had auto updated the night prior to this appearing, and put my entire system on a beta. There is no easy way to revert if you didn't do a time-machine save prior to updating (mine happened automatically, so I definitely didn't). Now I'm stuck building on my back-up mac until Apple releases 10.21.4 publicly.

Thanks for the help, lesson learned. Don't register for any beta software unless you have Time Machine setup to automatically backup your machine.

**UPDATE**

Reinstalling your OS when you are on BETA is actually quite easy.

1. Go to the Mac App Store
2. Search for "OS X El Capitan" or whatever OS you need
3. Hit the Download button

Now you can reinstall your OS. Stupid easy.

Comment: "and put my entire system on a beta" Oh for heaven's sake. Sorry you had to go through this, but this has to be a useful warning to everyone. — If you really need to submit now, there's an easy solution: install El Capitan (non-beta) on an external drive, boot from it, and do the submission.

Comment: I fortunately had a backup machine and was able to submit with that after going through the ring of permissions and certificate fire to set that one up. Good lesson learned. I'm puzzled why Apple would prevent OSX builds from doing the submission when Developers are more likely to beta their software. Great suggestion with the external drive. My 2 cents is make sure you backup if you EVER think of beta'ing anything for the OS. Unlike Xcode you can't just install multiple copies easily.